# Why does my clone fail in Scala?

Tags: scala

In the following I can clone the Hashtable but not the actual value

```
  val myHash = new HashMap[String, Int]
  myHash.put("A", 4)
  println(myHash("A").clone()) // fail
  myHash.clone() // works
```

I get the error cannot resolve symbol clone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HashMap is a [Clonable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Cloneable.html) while the Int is not.

I assume you expect to get an error since the int is in the map; however that is not a problem as clone is shallow. Clone will only create a new map and stuff all same keys and values into that.

Answer (score 9):

You can't clone a number. [`Int`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html) doesn't have a `clone()` method.

Comment: `BigInt` and `BigDecimal` can be cloned. It would be better to say one can't clone an `AnyVal`, which are equivalent to Java primitives, because the `clone` method is only present on `AnyRef`.